# C# Connecting client (local windows form application) to controller connected to computer via ethernet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sockets, user-interface, asyncsocket

I need to create a user interface to control a tool that is connected directly to my computer via an Ethernet cable. The controller is listening at a specified socket for connection requests.

When the connection is made the controller will broadcast streams of data.

I am currently looking to use client code similar to this example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx)

If I knew the IP address and the port number, would i be able to accomplish this connection? I'm new to socket programming so I'm not sure if this a good way to go about it.

Comment: Does the "tool" already exist, or are you creating that as well?

Comment: it exist's, i just need to connect to its controller. So i decided to use a windows form application running on my computer as the user interface to pull values that i need from the controller.

Comment: Is there documentation with the controller about the best way to create an interface for it?  Is there an API?

Answer (score 0):

If this controller is listening for socket connections and the application doesn't listen for incoming connection requests you only need a [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbhht5w(v=vs.110).aspx) object to start the communication.

Here is a basic [sample](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/TcpClientSample.htm).